# Is .class a method or field?

Tags: java, class

Any class in the java has a .class , I want to know .class is a static method or not? Or it is a public static field?

```
boolean alwaysTrue = (String.class == Class.forName("java.lang.String"));
```

Comment: I've read and re-read your question three times, and I am afraid I can't make any sense of it.

Comment: @aix: In Java, all classes (e.g., `String`) have a *[class literal](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#250782)* (`.class`) which is the [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) instance for that class. E.g., `String.class == Class.forName("java.lang.String")` (barring edge cases around classloaders and such).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Oh. I thought he was talking about class *files* :-)

Comment: @aix: Not an unreasonable thing to think. :-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Its neither.
It's a built-in language feature (a class literal) that looks like a public static final field.

Comment: Specifically, a *class literal*: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#250782

Answer (score 15):

When you write `.class` after a class name, it references the `Class` object that represents the given class. `.class` is used when there isn't an instance of the class available.

For example, if your class is `Print` (it is recommended that class name begin with an uppercase letter), then `Print.class` is an object that represents the class Print on runtime. It is the same object that is returned by the `getClass()` method of any (direct) instance of `Print.`

```
Print myPrint = new Print();
System.out.println(Print.class.getName());
System.out.println(myPrint.getClass().getName());
```

Comment: instance of a class is not the same as an object representing class type

Answer (score 5):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2

It's neither. It's an expression evaluated at compile time to the `Class` object for that class.

Comment: The third (current) edition is probably a better link; it also provides more details than the 2nd ed.

Comment: Thanks for the link!. Importantly Not "for that class", though, as it can be used on interfaces, annotations, etc.